# Highchart Vue - How includes momentjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, momentjs

I am trying to use `vue-highcharts` with `moment.js`.

```
<template>
    <highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="stockOptions" :updateArgs="[true, false]"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
...
    stockOptions: {
       series: [{
          data: ''
       }],
       plotOptions: {
          series: {
                turboThreshold: 0
          }
       },
       chart: {
            type: 'area'
       },
       time: {
            timezone: 'America/Sao_paulo'
       }
    }
...
</script>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Highcharts Error #25
Can't find Moment.js library
Using the global.timezone option requires the Moment.js library to be loaded.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Just include moment.js

Comment: I should think you do it just like you include anything else...using a `<script` tag...e.g. this one `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>` will load it from CDNJS (see https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/). Make sure you place the tag before the code which relies on it.

Comment: I'm using the webpack so I'm not adding the script tag in html. I tried to install a momentjs module but it did not work

Comment: Just because you're using webpack, AFAIK it doesn't prevent you from adding script tags if you need to, although of course it doesn't resolve the dependencies for you. I don't know what you did via webpack but perhaps it didn't load the scripts in the right order or something, it's difficult to be sure without seeing any detail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Highcharts checks whether the `moment.js` library is available on `window` scope, and that's why you need to add it there. First, you need to import two modules:

```
import Moment from "moment";
import MomentTimeZone from "moment-timezone";
```

Then run assign it as a `window` variable and call the `moment-timezone` module function:

```
window.moment = Moment
MomentTimeZone();
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n0v72938j

Comment: Or you can use this: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.moment ?